# npm update does not do anything

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

When I execute this code in my application folder where the package.json is located:

`npm update` or `npm update --save-dev` it does not do anything.

But when I do `npm outdated` is shows many outdated packages.

So how do I update all packages?

```
OS: Win 10 x64
nodejs: 6.2.2
npm:3.10.7

package.json

{
  "name": "tgb-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.14",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Running `npm update --dd` result in the follow extraction output:

```
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.490813,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor from cache
npm verb get saving protractor to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\protractor\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir already in flight; waiting
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: '"CEIBQS48U3970DBBLVY9BS6AW"',
npm verb headers   age: '128',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1222-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.490820,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js from cache
npm verb get saving zone.js to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\zone.js\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir already in flight; waiting
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-chrome-launcher
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: '"4F85C0FZBMRDOTDFPHJMQZBM8"',
npm verb headers   age: '59',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1231-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.492537,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-chrome-launcher from cache
npm verb get saving karma-chrome-launcher to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\karma-chrome-launcher\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir already in flight; waiting
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-remap-istanbul
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: '"BYUZKVHQIHLVUT104GP509OFK"',
npm verb headers   age: '268',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1221-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.490957,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-remap-istanbul from cache
npm verb get saving karma-remap-istanbul to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\karma-remap-istanbul\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir already in flight; waiting
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tslint
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: '"CWO8LZOC4DK34K142T9LWM1RX"',
npm verb headers   age: '10',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1248-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.490976,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/tslint from cache
npm verb get saving tslint to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\tslint\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir already in flight; waiting
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-spec-reporter
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: '"1TKJPMC6QAX7DTKI3RCPOWB33"',
npm verb headers   age: '59',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1235-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.496023,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-spec-reporter from cache
npm verb get saving jasmine-spec-reporter to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\jasmine-spec-reporter\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir already in flight; waiting
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: '"BTWWBQ9R8BXMY0349REWK133W"',
npm verb headers   age: '252',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1227-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '9',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.501994,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript from cache
npm verb get saving typescript to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\typescript\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir already in flight; waiting
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: '"36V4PLV1VKGDW8C5GXL8K8BVH"',
npm verb headers   age: '211',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1240-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.498463,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine from cache
npm verb get saving karma-jasmine to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\karma-jasmine\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir already in flight; waiting
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: '"9B0FRZQ5V9W9AIXWF98UVSM6C"',
npm verb headers   age: '97',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1224-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.501606,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/karma from cache
npm verb get saving karma to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\karma\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir already in flight; waiting
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-cli
npm verb headers { server: 'CouchDB/1.5.0 (Erlang OTP/R16B03)',
npm verb headers   etag: '"BZP1VT7P2AOLYBNMO7N10ESCI"',
npm verb headers   'content-type': 'application/json',
npm verb headers   'content-encoding': 'gzip',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   'content-length': '2902',
npm verb headers   'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
npm verb headers   date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   age: '56',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1233-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.496210,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb get saving karma-cli to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\karma-cli\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fforms
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
npm verb headers   etag: '"EAEQ3H227F67DKL54RON412OW"',
npm verb headers   age: '0',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1238-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.485421,VS0,VE259',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fforms from cache
npm verb get saving @angular/forms to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\_40angular_252fforms\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser-dynamic
                                                                                            npm verb headers { 'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
npm verb headers   'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
npm verb headers   date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1250-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.475204,VS0,VE419',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser-dynamic from cache
npm verb get saving @angular/platform-browser-dynamic to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\_40angular_252fplatform-browser-dynamic\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser
                                                                                                          npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
                                                                                                                              npm verb headers   etag: '"6KULKVAP2JLLHXUR9G1MKEWBH"',
npm verb headers   age: '0',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1247-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.481265,VS0,VE428',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser from cache
npm verb get saving @angular/platform-browser to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\_40angular_252fplatform-browser\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
                                                                       [..................] | : verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2frouter
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
npm verb headers   etag: '"E37EYJC1EI89JHFLMFG79P1B1"',
npm verb headers   age: '0',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1247-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.481239,VS0,VE452',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2frouter from cache
npm verb get saving @angular/router to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\_40angular_252frouter\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasmine
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
npm verb headers   etag: '"5970JWNJE5EMJ1LQCUJLDE51A"',
npm verb headers   age: '0',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1249-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.480305,VS0,VE717',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasmine from cache
npm verb get saving @types/jasmine to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\_40types_252fjasmine\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
npm verb headers   etag: '"5T3TIRLH7GIKTLAUE8ASZODQP"',
npm verb headers   age: '0',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1237-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.478583,VS0,VE741',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon from cache
npm verb get saving @angular/common to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\_40angular_252fcommon\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
npm verb headers   etag: '"7SNBRHEXD0EH21E7G01GBSPZ0"',
npm verb headers   age: '0',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1232-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.485587,VS0,VE764',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler from cache
npm verb get saving @angular/compiler to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\_40angular_252fcompiler\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore
npm verb headers { date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:10 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
npm verb headers   etag: '"4J1XWC967WZ1FEYDRY04JS2DN"',
npm verb headers   age: '0',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1245-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.482388,VS0,VE783',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore from cache
npm verb get saving @angular/core to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\_40angular_252fcore\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fhttp
npm verb headers { 'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
npm verb headers   'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
npm verb headers   date: 'Wed, 28 Sep 2016 21:45:11 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1230-FRA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1475099110.484580,VS0,VE784',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fhttp from cache
npm verb get saving @angular/http to C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\_40angular_252fhttp\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\elisabeth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb outdated not updating @angular/common because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating @angular/compiler because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating @angular/core because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating @angular/forms because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating @angular/http because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating @angular/platform-browser because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating @angular/platform-browser-dynamic because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating @angular/router because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating angular-cli because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating codelyzer because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating jasmine-core because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating jasmine-spec-reporter because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating karma because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating protractor because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating ts-node because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating tslint because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb outdated not updating typescript because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

Comment: delete your node_modules folder. do npm cache clean and try again

Comment: @ojf that did not work. Errors about errors... not worth posting here.

Comment: so..windows, ios, linux?

Comment: its written above long ago :-)

Comment: i need to use sudo that helps :)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The `npm update --dd` output says why at the end:

`...not updating @angular/common because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range`

Look at this specific package, `angular/common`. You have it set to `2.0.0`, which means npm **will always fetch that specific version**. If you want the package to update, you need to use a semver range. You can view a comprehensive list of semver ranges [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#advanced-range-syntax), but the most commonly used are probably `~` and `^`.

`~` means that the patch version will update. So if you have version `~1.2.1`, it will update to any `1.2.x`, but never to `1.3.0`.

`^` updates the minor version, so if you have `^1.2.1`, it will update to any `1.x.x` release, but never to `2.0.0`.

Comment: But that would mean that 'npm outdated' does not respect the semver ranges else it would not say that angular 2 common is outdated for example, right?

Comment: @Elisabeth ```npm outdated``` shows you two different things: 1) Wanted: which is the latest version which satisfies semver ranges written in package.json 2) Latest: which is the absolute latest version of the module that is available on npm.

[npm outdated man page](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated)

Comment: Reading https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated ah you wrote my mind hehe, yes according to semver I am already on wanted, so I have to tweak the package.json.

Comment: More precisely: `~` updates patch version and fixes major and minor version. `^` updates patch and minor versions and fixes major version.

Comment: I have the npm module `compression ^1.7.2`.  npm-check-updates says that 1.7.4 is available, but npm update does not update this package.

Comment: That's very useful! Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for some packages. I have `"@fluentui/react-icons": "^0.3.10"` in my package.json, `npm outdated` shows current and wanted as 0.3.10 and latest as 0.4.1, but `npm update --dd` says "npm verb outdated not updating @fluentui/react-icons because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range"

Comment: It's worth to mention any version starting with 0.* will not update minor even with ^. Semver does not consider 0.* versions stable. @ChristopherHaws, not just a specific package. I spent several hours to figure this out when trying to npm up dd-trace (from 0.22.2 to 0.33.2)

Comment: @L.Holanda damn. It should be at the top of the comment section, event part of the answer

Answer (score 55):

To update, here are the steps:

1. Running `npm outdated` will allow you to check all the packages that need to be updated. The list will show **current**, **wanted** and **latest** version of each package.
2. Next, run `npm update` which will update all the packages to the latest *possible* version as defined in `package.json`. For example, if a certain package in `package.json` has version **^2.3.1** then this package will not be updated beyond **2.x.x**, and if a package has version **~5.3.2** then it will not be updated beyond **5.3.x**. (to understand semantic versioning, [read this](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning))
3. But what if you want to update to the latest, and the versions of your packages in `package.json` are preventing you from updating as described in step 2 above? Well there are two solutions.

   a) You can manually update the package versions in `package.json` by changing the versions of your packages to the latest values you like them to be. Although this might work, this is very tedious and error prone. **So I do not recommend it.**

   b) You can automatically update the versions of your packages in `package.json`. To do so, you need to install the `npm-check-updates` package (I typically install this package globally) using this command: `npm i -g npm-check-updates`. Once this is done, you have to run `ncu -u`. This will only update the package versions in `package.json` to the latest version. You may be requested to run `npm install` to install the latest version available. **I recommend this method.**
4. Now, after updating the versions of your packages in `package.json`, run `npm update` and your packages will be updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 15):

If `npm [-g] outdated` shows outdated packages *outside* of the semver range (e.g. a major update), the `update` command *cannot* be used to update these packages.

To install the latest version, explicitly specify the package with

```
npm install [-g] <package>
```

Comment: I do not recommend this approach. You are installing a package globally because you could not update your package locally. This is an unnecessary overhead, and to be honest, might lead to bigger problems down the road.

Comment: @Greeso - I agree an outdated local package should not be installed globally. The point is if you have an outdated _global_ package, you need the `-g` flag (that's why it's in brackets, it's only required in some cases). I also added it to the `outdated` command to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4):

When I was very new to Node.js I didn't knew the following. I'm sharing if it might help you.

*npm version:*

```
npm --version
```

*Note that following also checks for npm version:*

```
npm --version <packagename> // package name argument is simply ignored
```

*Package version:*

```
npm list // at local directory to check local package versions
npm list -g // to check global package versions
```

Comment: Useful knowledge for those that don't know these commands however, your answer doesn't correspond to the question.

Comment: This SAVED me. ty!

Answer (score 4):

Update all outdated packages to latest version with one liner on bash

```
npm outdated | cut -d" " -f1 | tail -n +2 | sed 's/$/@latest/' | xargs npm i
```

If you are using `^` or `~` or in front of your versions, then you `cannot` get the next major version of that package with `npm update <package-name>`.
You could check your outdated packages using `npm outdated` and run `npm install <package-name>@latest` for each of them, the above one liner will do all this for you

Answer (score 3):

You can force update all packages **even if it breaks semantic versioning** using an existing package.

*Use this with care for important projects and absolutely avoid in production.*

I find this shortcut useful for personal projects.

This package will update all the dependency versions in `package.json` and the following install command with install them.

`npx npm-check-updates -u && npm i`

Answer (score 2):

One more thing to check that could be affecting the way you install packages and ultimately causing this problem is your .npmrc file.  Check to see if it has a line like:

```
save-exact=true
```

If it does, then remove it or set it to false. When it is set to true, you get the following behavior:

> Dependencies saved to package.json using --save, --save-dev or --save-optional will be configured with an exact version rather than using npm’s default semver range operator.

[.npmrc and save-exact](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-exact)

Answer (score 0):

for me, i saw as soon as I included `--save` it was updating the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed and reinstalled it and the latest one was installed for me!

```
npm remove <package name> 
npm install <package name>
```