# react-dev-utils latest version installs a vulnerable version of browserslist

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, package.json, cve

`react-dev-utils@11.0.4` installing a vulnerable version of browserlist, `browserslist@4.14.2`, although we have updated package on github. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-dev-utils/package.json#L57

[to test out, you may simple create any folder and do `npm i react-dev-utils` and then check it using `npm ls browserlist`]

I dont get, what all are the constraint for this. (I dont see any `package-lock.json` for this package, which could be a potential reason for the vuln). older version has reported vulnerability [CVE-2021-23364](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-w8qv-6jwh-64r5).

Comment: FYI, there is no actual security issue for `react-dev-tools` here, since it doesn't parse user-provided browser queries.

Comment: okay thanks, that might be the case probably, but anyways I want update package to one without any reported vulns.

Answer (score 1):

> `react-dev-utils@11.0.4` installing a vulnerable version of `browserlist`, `browserslist@4.14.2`, although we have updated package on github

This is because that `package.json` file resides in the default branch which usually contains the latest or development code. At the time you posted the question, that change was not published to the npm registry.

`react-dev-utils@11.0.4` has `browserslist@4.14.2` listed in its package so that's the version that will be installed. Reference: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dev-utils@11.0.4/package.json

You need atleast `react-dev-utils@12.0.0` to fix that vulnerability. See the [versions tab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dev-utils?activeTab=versions).

---

> [to test out, you may simple create any folder and do `npm i react-dev-utils` and then check it using `npm ls browserlist`]

Running that command will install the latest version of `react-dev-utils`, which now has no vulnerability. So it will fix your issue.

---

> I dont see any package-lock.json for this package, which could be a potential reason for the vuln

`package-lock.json` cannot be published to registry, only the top level lock file is respected. Reference: [Should package-lock.json also be published?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44546718/11613622)

---

> this may be an example package, but how in general we update to latest package? have tried npm update as well.

`npm update` respects the [semver range](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning) that you've set in your `package.json`. If its like `"react-dev-utils": "11.0.4"` that command won't do anything. If its `"react-dev-utils": "^11.0.4"`, it will try to update to the latest `11.x.x` version which you are already on, so again it won't do anything. Reference: [npm update does not do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39758042/11613622)

In general if you want to upgrade every direct dependency to latest version you can use [`npm-check-updates`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) before running `npm update`. Refer https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version for detailed guide. Related: [How to update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16073603/11613622)

Now, if it is not a direct dependency, as was in your case, you can force resolutions. This is natively supported in Yarn and NPM v8.3.0 and above. In older NPM versions you need to use a dependency like [`npm-force-resolutions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions). Related thread: [npm equivalent of yarn resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52416312/11613622)

There are much more related threads that you can easily find by searching on the web.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, will dig deeper and try to understand. its not just about this single package in create-react-app, but many others. will take the approach you suggested and if further issues, will ask in thread. thanks!