# Npm failing to update versions

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-package

I am attempting to update my npm packages. I have been having problems with what I believe I should do compared to what is happening.

Reference to https://docs.npmjs.com/updating-packages-downloaded-from-the-registry

I ran the **npm update -dd** and there were no relevant issues with the update. I am running in Windows 10.

The steps I found to perform the update are:

```
%> npm outdated  # to see all the packages that need to be updated
%> npm update    # to perform the update
%> npm outdated  # there should be no packages listed
```

Below are the results of my running the above commands

```
e:\app>npm outdated
Package                                  Current         Wanted          Latest  Location                                        Depended by
@angular-devkit/build-angular            0.900.7        0.900.7          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular      app
@angular/cdk                               9.2.4          9.2.4          14.2.4  node_modules/@angular/cdk                       app
@angular/common                           9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/common                    app
@angular/compiler                         9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/compiler                  app
@angular/compiler-cli                     9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli              app
@angular/core                             9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/core                      app
@angular/flex-layout               9.0.0-beta.31  9.0.0-beta.31  14.0.0-beta.40  node_modules/@angular/flex-layout               app
@angular/forms                            9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/forms                     app
@angular/language-service                 9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/language-service          app
@angular/material                          9.2.4          9.2.4          14.2.4  node_modules/@angular/material                  app
@angular/platform-browser                 9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser          app
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic         9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic  app
@angular/platform-server                  9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/platform-server           app
@angular/router                           9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/router                    app
@types/jasmine                            3.10.6         3.10.6           4.3.0  node_modules/@types/jasmine                     app
@types/node                             12.20.55       12.20.55          18.8.3  node_modules/@types/node                        app
angular-email-editor                       0.7.1          0.7.1           0.9.0  node_modules/angular-email-editor               app
codelyzer                                  5.2.2          5.2.2           6.0.2  node_modules/codelyzer                          app
core-js                                   2.6.12         2.6.12          3.25.5  node_modules/core-js                            app
date-fns                                  1.30.1         1.30.1          2.29.3  node_modules/date-fns                           app
html-webpack-plugin                        3.2.0          3.2.0           5.5.0  node_modules/html-webpack-plugin                app
jasmine-core                              3.99.1         3.99.1           4.4.0  node_modules/jasmine-core                       app
jasmine-spec-reporter                      4.2.1          4.2.1           7.0.0  node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter              app
karma                                      4.1.0          4.1.0           6.4.1  node_modules/karma                              app
karma-chrome-launcher                      2.2.0          2.2.0           3.1.1  node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher              app
karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter           2.1.1          2.1.1           3.0.3  node_modules/karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter   app
karma-jasmine                              2.0.1          2.0.1           5.1.0  node_modules/karma-jasmine                      app
karma-jasmine-html-reporter                1.7.0          1.7.0           2.0.0  node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter        app
ngx-clipboard                             12.3.1         12.3.1          15.1.0  node_modules/ngx-clipboard                      app
ngx-cookie                                 4.1.2          4.1.2           6.0.1  node_modules/ngx-cookie                         app
ngx-cookie-service                         2.4.0          2.4.0          14.0.1  node_modules/ngx-cookie-service                 app
ngx-toastr                                12.1.0         12.1.0          15.2.0  node_modules/ngx-toastr                         app
protractor                                 5.4.4          5.4.4           7.0.0  node_modules/protractor                         app
rxjs                                       6.5.5          6.5.5           7.5.7  node_modules/rxjs                               app
stripe                                   8.222.0        8.222.0         10.13.0  node_modules/stripe                             app
stripe-angular                             0.5.1          0.5.1           1.7.0  node_modules/stripe-angular                     app
ts-node                                    7.0.1          7.0.1          10.9.1  node_modules/ts-node                            app
tslib                                     1.14.1         1.14.1           2.4.0  node_modules/tslib                              app
tslint                                    5.15.0         5.15.0           6.1.3  node_modules/tslint                             app
typescript                                 3.7.7          3.7.7           4.8.4  node_modules/typescript                         app
webpack                                   4.46.0         4.46.0          5.74.0  node_modules/webpack                            app
zone.js                                   0.10.3         0.10.3          0.11.8  node_modules/zone.js                            app
```

And then..

```
e:\app>npm update

up to date, audited 1859 packages in 34s

100 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

42 vulnerabilities (1 low, 14 moderate, 23 high, 4 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

e:\app>
```

And finally the running of **npm outdated** with no evident changes.

```
e:\app>npm outdated
Package                                  Current         Wanted          Latest  Location                                        Depended by
@angular-devkit/build-angular            0.900.7        0.900.7          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular      app
@angular/cdk                               9.2.4          9.2.4          14.2.4  node_modules/@angular/cdk                       app
@angular/common                           9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/common                    app
@angular/compiler                         9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/compiler                  app
@angular/compiler-cli                     9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli              app
@angular/core                             9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/core                      app
@angular/flex-layout               9.0.0-beta.31  9.0.0-beta.31  14.0.0-beta.40  node_modules/@angular/flex-layout               app
@angular/forms                            9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/forms                     app
@angular/language-service                 9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/language-service          app
@angular/material                          9.2.4          9.2.4          14.2.4  node_modules/@angular/material                  app
@angular/platform-browser                 9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser          app
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic         9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic  app
@angular/platform-server                  9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/platform-server           app
@angular/router                           9.1.13         9.1.13          14.2.5  node_modules/@angular/router                    app
@types/jasmine                            3.10.6         3.10.6           4.3.0  node_modules/@types/jasmine                     app
@types/node                             12.20.55       12.20.55          18.8.3  node_modules/@types/node                        app
angular-email-editor                       0.7.1          0.7.1           0.9.0  node_modules/angular-email-editor               app
codelyzer                                  5.2.2          5.2.2           6.0.2  node_modules/codelyzer                          app
core-js                                   2.6.12         2.6.12          3.25.5  node_modules/core-js                            app
date-fns                                  1.30.1         1.30.1          2.29.3  node_modules/date-fns                           app
html-webpack-plugin                        3.2.0          3.2.0           5.5.0  node_modules/html-webpack-plugin                app
jasmine-core                              3.99.1         3.99.1           4.4.0  node_modules/jasmine-core                       app
jasmine-spec-reporter                      4.2.1          4.2.1           7.0.0  node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter              app
karma                                      4.1.0          4.1.0           6.4.1  node_modules/karma                              app
karma-chrome-launcher                      2.2.0          2.2.0           3.1.1  node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher              app
karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter           2.1.1          2.1.1           3.0.3  node_modules/karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter   app
karma-jasmine                              2.0.1          2.0.1           5.1.0  node_modules/karma-jasmine                      app
karma-jasmine-html-reporter                1.7.0          1.7.0           2.0.0  node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter        app
ngx-clipboard                             12.3.1         12.3.1          15.1.0  node_modules/ngx-clipboard                      app
ngx-cookie                                 4.1.2          4.1.2           6.0.1  node_modules/ngx-cookie                         app
ngx-cookie-service                         2.4.0          2.4.0          14.0.1  node_modules/ngx-cookie-service                 app
ngx-toastr                                12.1.0         12.1.0          15.2.0  node_modules/ngx-toastr                         app
protractor                                 5.4.4          5.4.4           7.0.0  node_modules/protractor                         app
rxjs                                       6.5.5          6.5.5           7.5.7  node_modules/rxjs                               app
stripe                                   8.222.0        8.222.0         10.13.0  node_modules/stripe                             app
stripe-angular                             0.5.1          0.5.1           1.7.0  node_modules/stripe-angular                     app
ts-node                                    7.0.1          7.0.1          10.9.1  node_modules/ts-node                            app
tslib                                     1.14.1         1.14.1           2.4.0  node_modules/tslib                              app
tslint                                    5.15.0         5.15.0           6.1.3  node_modules/tslint                             app
typescript                                 3.7.7          3.7.7           4.8.4  node_modules/typescript                         app
webpack                                   4.46.0         4.46.0          5.74.0  node_modules/webpack                            app
zone.js                                   0.10.3         0.10.3          0.11.8  node_modules/zone.js                            app
```

I'm assuming I missed something simple.

Thank you for any help you have to provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm update does not do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758042/npm-update-does-not-do-anything)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion provided at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758042/npm-update-does-not-do-anything. There are no errors provided with this and the update is not performed. I checked the package.json and there were not changes to the versions there.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I can perform the updates but it is a little more of a manual process.

For all **@angular** and **nguniversal** packages, I have to update those manually from major version to major version. I was behind several major versions.

It appears that the other packages can be updated with the npm update across multiple major versions. Still working on getting everything back up and running but I believe I am on a good start.

Happy coding to you all.